# Using random forest on time series data with timetk library in R

Tags: r

Random forest can predict one step ahead forecasts on time series. The r library timetk  augments the data signature, basically splitting up day,month,year to integers. Can random forest predictions be made past one step using the augmented time index? I am creating a hold out sample by splitting up my data but keeping the augmented date integers in test predictions, because they are know in advance. Any help is appreciated.